# django-signal instance to email sending attribute encoding

Tags: django, django-signals, django-email

Good day. The model with signal must send to email instance, but i've got traceback which i place after codeblock

```
class ParticipantModel(models.Model):

TYPE_USER = (
    ('O', 'Онлайн трансляция'),
    ('P', 'Персональное присутствие'),
)
name = models.CharField( max_length=256, verbose_name='Имя')
surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
position = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Должность')
company = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название компании')
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Город')
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Электро почта')
phone = models.CharField(max_length="50", verbose_name="Телефон")
phonem = models.CharField(max_length="50", verbose_name="Мобильный телефон")
www = models.URLField(verbose_name="Сайт")
tuser = models.CharField(max_length='250', choices=TYPE_USER, verbose_name="Форма вашего участия")
class Meta:
    verbose_name = ('Участник')
    verbose_name_plural = ('Участники')

def send_marketing(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    message = instance
    subject = "McAfee day"
    from_email = 'bakotech.events@gmail.com'
    recipient_list = ('sergey@avetisyan.com.ua', 'marketing@bakotech.com')
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
post_save.connect(send_marketing, sender=ParticipantModel)
```

Traceback:

AttributeError at /reg
'ParticipantModel' object has no attribute 'encode'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'ParticipantModel' object has no attribute 'encode'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py in encode_7or8bit, line 73
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:
['.',
 '',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sergey/djprojects/venvs/bakoevents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Срд, 11 Сен 2013 19:49:00 +0300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing your instance in where the email class expects a string:

```
message = instance
...
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

You need to use a string instead.